# How many possible solutions in difference of perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was just wondering if there is a general way besides trial and error to find all possible integer solutions for the following equation or that there are infinitely many solutions.

$a^2-b^2 = 32$

with the conditions

$a > b > 0$

$32$ could also be replaced with any other number

Comment: $(a+b)(a-b) = 32.$ With your restrictions, both factors are positive powers of $2$

Comment: Infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There will always be finitely many solutions for $a^2 - b^2 = k$ for any given $k$, and the proof is pretty simple - the difference between $x^2$ and $(x+1)^2$ is $2x+1$, so for any $x$ such that $2x + 1 > k$, the gap between consecutive primes is too large to allow any solutions.

As to finding particular solutions, Will Jagy points out a very helpful trick - since $a^2 - b^2 = (a + b)(a - b)$, the factorisation of $k$ will tell you something about the sum and/or difference of the two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As Will Jagy suggests, factor $a^2-b^2$ as $(a+b)(a-b)$, whereupon you have

$$
(a+b)(a-b) = k
$$

Note that $a+b$ and $a-b$ must have the same parity—that is, they are either both even or both odd.  (Do you see why?)  Thus, if $k$ is even, we look at all ways to factor $k$ into two distinct even numbers; if $k$ is odd, we look at all ways to factor $k$ into two distinct odd numbers (it will be impossible for any factor to be even).  For any given way, suppose the two numbers are $m$ and $n$, with $m > n$.  Then

$$
a = \frac{m+n}{2}
$$

and

$$
b = \frac{m-n}{2}
$$

This should convince you that there is always a finite number of solutions.